# Trying to connect Pandas with PostgreSQL without exposing user credentials

Tags: pandas, postgresql

I am new to programming and this is first post for help.
Can anyone please help me with using environment variables instead of original username and password when connecting Pandas using SQL Alchemy with PostgreSQL, in Windows.

I have tried using Environment variables System settings but I am getting the following error:
Operational Error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user

Some code for your reference:

```
>>>from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>>import psycopg2
>>>engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/sample_db')
```

I am trying to hide DB credentials instead of exposing them.

Please let me know for any other details and, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Who are you trying to hide them from?

If you put the password in [the ~/.pgpass file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) (spelled `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` on Windows), it will work with SQLalchemy just like it will for a wide variety of other clients.  Just remove the password from the URL, and will automatically be looked up in this file and used.

Of course anyone who can see .pgpass can, well, see it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have not tried this as I am new to this. But will surely act on your suggestion soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

file `.secret`:

```py
user:pass@locahost:5432
```

and in `main.py`:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

with open('.secret') as f:
    SECRET = f.read().strip()

ENGINE = create_engine(f'postgresql://{SECRET}/sample_db')
```